# Extracting text from PDF -Tokenize TypeError

Tags: python, pdf, extract

When trying to extract text from PDF's using Textract, I get a TypeError: "cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". Can anyone be helpful with what might be an solution?
When I print(text), I get the text from the PDF I want extracted, though in a bit strange format. However, text[0] etc only contain numbers..?

```
import textract
import os
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

for filename in os.listdir('Harbour PDF'):
if '.DS_Store' == filename:
    continue
filename = 'Harbour PDF/' + filename
print(filename)

text = textract.process(filename)
print(text)

tokens = word_tokenize(text)
keywords = [word for word in word_tokenize(text,'english',False)]
```

Error:

File "scrapePort.py", line 15, in 
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py", line 143, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py", line 105, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1269, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1323, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1323, in 
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1313, in span_tokenize
    for sl in slices:
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1354, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 317, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/Users/Rasmus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1327, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
**TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object**

Comment: Please share the pdf in question for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to decode your data first.

```
text.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Try this

```
 tokens = word_tokenize(text.decode("utf-8"))
```